# audio clip.paused is undefined when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a very simple javascript function to play and pause an HTML audio file. From testing I can tell that the below function works perfectly when I use document.getElementById, but when I try to use jQuery the .paused is undefined.

```
function playAudio(audioID){
    var clip = $("#" + audioID);
    console.log(clip);
    console.log(clip.paused);
    if (clip.paused){
        clip.play();
    }
    else{
        clip.pause();
    }
}
```

This is called by an onclick call:

```
<img src="media/play.png" class="play" onclick="playAudio('audio1');">
```

When I log clip, it returns the proper audio file. But when I try to log if paused is true or false, the console says that it is undefined.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#" + audioID)` does not give you the audio element like `document.getElementById` would, it gives you a jQuery object which encapsulates the audio element.
If you want to access the properties of the audio element you will have to expose it from the jQuery object.
To expose a property from the jQuery object you can use `.prop()` (`if (clip.prop('paused')){`), you can also expose the element itself with `.get()` and `[]`

```
function playAudio(audioID){
    var clip = $("#" + audioID);
    console.log(clip[0]);
    console.log(clip.prop('paused'));
    if (clip.prop('paused')){
        clip[0].play();
    }
    else{
        clip.get(0).pause();
    }
}
```